# How to extract the image (basically MAT) from Poly draw from OPENCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am writing a simple opencv program to extract the image and get the Matrix of image from a ploy drawed by myself. The code below gives a example of drawing a poly with a few points given, when I finished drawing the poly in red color, I wanted to use findContours to extract the only poly out of picture and get matrix from that contour.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat grey_img;
Mat img_resized;
bool start = 0;
cv::Point lastPoint =  Point(-1,-1);
vector<Point> parkspoint;
void mouseMode2(int event, int x, int y, void* param);
void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
    mouseMode2(event,x,y,param);
}

void mouseMode2(int event, int x, int y, void* param){
    //Boolean select_flag = CV_EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY; 
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && start)
    {
        cout<<"select one point  "<<x<<"   "<< y<<endl;
        cv::Point point = cv::Point(x, y);

        cout<<"last point   x:"<<lastPoint.x <<"    y:"<<lastPoint.y<<endl; 
        //  add point
        if(lastPoint.x!=-1 && lastPoint.y!=-1){
           cv::line(img_resized, lastPoint, point, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 1, 0);
           cv::imshow("parking", img_resized);
        }
        cout<<"add point to array"<<endl;
        lastPoint =  Point(x,y);        
        parkspoint.push_back(point);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && start){
        cv::Point point = cv::Point(x, y);
        if(lastPoint.x!=-1 && lastPoint.y!=-1)
        {
            cv::Mat img1 = img_resized.clone();
            cv::line(img1, lastPoint, point, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 1, 0);
            cv::imshow("parking", img1);
        }
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_RBUTTONUP )
    {
        cout<<"end selecting"<<endl;
        start = 0;
        if(lastPoint.x!=-1 && lastPoint.y!=-1){
            cv::line(img_resized, lastPoint, parkspoint[0], CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 1, 0);
            cv::imshow("parking", img_resized);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<parkspoint.size();i++){
            cout<<"show points "<<i<<"     "<< parkspoint[i].x<<":"<< parkspoint[i].y <<endl;
        }

        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
        cv::imshow("parking", img_resized);

        cv::findContours(img_resized,contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        cout<<"find  how many coutours  : "<< contours.size()<< endl;
        for(int i = 0;i <contours.size();i++){
           cv::drawContours(grey_img,contours,i,cv::Scalar(255,0,0),1);
        }
        cv::imshow("parking2", grey_img);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        cout<<"start selecting"<<endl;
        start = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat img_raw = imread("D:/car parking/bb.jpg", 1); // load as color image

    resize(img_raw, img_resized, Size(64,128) );
    grey_img = img_resized.clone();

    cout << "raw img dimensions: " << img_raw.cols << " width x " << img_raw.rows << "height" << endl;
    cout << "img dimensions: " << img_resized.cols << " width x " << img_resized.rows << "height" << endl; 

    cv::cvtColor(img_resized,img_resized,CV_BGR2GRAY);
   namedWindow("parking",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
   imshow("parking",img_resized);
   namedWindow("parking2",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
   imshow("parking2",grey_img);
   cv::setMouseCallback("parking",mouseHandler,0);
   waitKey(0);
   return 0;
}
```

However, I met with problems that [image], the left image is the poly I draw by myself, when applied with findContour, it gave me three polys.

First, the largest contour is the rectangle of the whole picture, which I don't want it, I could compare the size of contour to get rid of it, but if there is any other good/smart way to get rid of the big rectangle in prior.

Second, there are two contour are much similar,more like outer and inner border of the shape I draw, that Mat of any contour is what I want for the final result. you expect me to use any of this contour, pick any one is ok.  but what if I draw many shapes, for each shape gives birth a brother, then it is complicated to sort them out

This is the end result I expect, the cropped image 
[image]

Comment: why not just get the [boundingrect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) for the points you were already *drawing*, and crop that ?

Comment: in the example, I have draw a rectangle, but in reality, it can be any shapes more than rectangle

Comment: i maybe misunderstood you on *extract*, but if you want to crop parts, those can only be rectangles again.

Comment: All I want is to crop parts, the parts can be any shape by linking these points. There can be at least 3 points, or at most 8 points